# How to Bind the Image Source according the selected item?

Tags: wpf, button, data-binding, listbox

How to Bind the Image Source according to the selected item from a listbox that contains items with a property Image?

```
<Button Name="btn">  
<Button.Header>      
   <StackPanel>      
     <Image name="img">
   <StackPanel>
</Button.Header>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the information you have provided i would do it as follows

```
<Button Name="btn">  
  <Button.Header>      
   <StackPanel>      
     <Image name="img" Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Image, ElementName=myListBox}" />
   <StackPanel>
  </Button.Header>
</Button>

<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">

</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Binding like this:

```
<Image name="img" Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Image, ElementName=myListBox}" />
```